# Green Screen tracking marker crunch?

Tags: tracking, masking

So I found a website that provides practice green screen plates for you to work with, they also provide some general tips on what you can do to track the shot effectively. However im just getting into keying and tracking and im having trouble translating those tips into a blender friendly workflow...like how do you do "two keyers, one that makes the girl look good, and one that crunches out the markers, and crossfade between them with a garbage matte"

[Here's](https://www.hollywoodcamerawork.com/green-screen-plates.html) the website, they provide the image sequences for all the plates for anyone else interested, and its completely free.

Below is just an image from the shot im trying to track.

[image]

Comment: How to do this is not the hard part, it (relatively) is finding out what they mean by “crunches out the markers“ and “garbage matte.“

Comment: Yes exactly, I found a good tutorial from CG Cookie  on Garbage mattes here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_CiCjuG7y4&t=72s) , but how do we the crunching part?